# Which GPIO pin is floating, pulled up or down?

Tags: gpio

I found a [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=178822&p=1139652#p1139233) and a comment saying:

> (... omitted ...)
>    only GPIOs 28,29 44 & 45 float. 0-8 have default internal 50k pulls high, the rest default pull low. Additionally, there are strong pulls up for whichever I2C peripheral appears at pins 3 & 5 on the GPIO header (GPIOs 2&3 on the majority of Pi models.
>   (... omitted ...)

But, Raspberry Pi doesn't have a pin numbered larger than 40!

I wonder if it is true or not, and if available, I want to see the (official) reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

The Pi has 54 GPIO numbered 0 to 53.  GPIO 0-27 are brought out to pins on the current 40-pin expansion header.  The other GPIO are generally inaccessible.

See [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) page 102 first column in table for the power-up GPIO pull state.

In addition GPIO 2/3 used for I2C have hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3 fitted.  A fact you can confirm by examining the board and the [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md).

Comment: Thanks. I need to use *floating* pin. According to the datasheet, 28, 29, 44, and 45 are floating, but they are inaccessible. Then, Raspberry Pi isn't suitable for my purpose?

Comment: @Jeon - those are the default power-up pulls.  You can change the settings in software (apart from the hard-wired GPIO 2/3).  E.g. [pigs pud 4 o](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PUD) switches off the pull on GPIO 4.

Comment: That's great. I am using wiringPi instead of  pigpio. I found the same functionality `pullUpDnControl()`. Many thanks!